# Passing style directive value to a component in Vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3, vue-directives, vue-styleguidist

I am trying to add padding to a shared button component through :style directive.
For some reasons, the changes doesn't show up on the button. This shared component requires different padding based on different scenario so I cannot add it directly inside my button.vue

I'm new to Vuejs and would really appreciate if anyone can suggest the problem.

```
        <Button
          @on-click="currentStep = 2"
          :text= "Next"
          :style="padding: 12px 15px 12px 15px"
        />
```

Answer (score 0):

If you bind something in Vue, then the value that you pass is JavaScript code.

In your case `padding: 12px 15px 12px 15px` will be interpret as JavaScript and it is not a valid JavaScript line.

So if you want to pass a text, then use quotes around it, like

```
:style="'padding: 12px 15px 12px 15px'"
```

You can also pass an object instead

```
:style="{ padding: '12px 15px 12px 15px' }"
```

### Playground

```js
Vue.createApp({
  data() {
    return {
      myStyle: { color: 'green' }
    }
  }
}).mount('#app')
```

```css
#app { line-height: 1.75; }
[v-cloak] { display: none; }
.comment { color: #A0A0A0}
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <button :style="'color: red'">red</button><br/>
  <button :style="{ color: 'blue' }">blue</button><br/>
  <button :style="myStyle">green</button> 
  <span class="comment"> &#8592; over data property</span><br/>
</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried all the above ways to add padding but still the button doesn't show up required changes. Do you know of any other alternative or issue that might be causing this?